# Sum Value if Two Specific Values Occur on the Same Day

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've got a dataset that has species' harvest by weapon type by dates.  Data set example below:

```
Species  Total  HarvestMonthDayYear  WeaponID  WeaponType
Deer     623    1/14/2017            1         Gun
Deer     10     1/14/2017            3         Reg Bow
Deer     15     1/14/2017            4         Crossbow
Deer     5      9/20/2017            4         Crossbow
Deer     9      9/21/2017            2         Muzzleloader
Deer     2      9/21/2017            3         Reg Bow
Deer     1      9/21/2017            4         Crossbow
Deer     1      9/21/2017            8         Shotgun
Deer     10     9/22/2017            1         Gun
Deer     1      9/22/2017            3         Reg Bow
```

What I would to accomplish is that when "Reg Bow" and "Crossbow" harvest on the same day, I would like to combine the results into one row named "Archery". And the final data set should look like:

```
Species Total  HarvestMonthDayYear  WeaponID  WeaponType
Deer    623    1/14/2017            1         Gun
Deer    25     1/14/2017            10        Archery
Deer    5      9/20/2017            4         Crossbow
Deer    9      9/21/2017            2         Muzzleloader
Deer    3      9/21/2017            10        Archery
Deer    1      9/21/2017            8         Shotgun
Deer    10     9/22/2017            1         Gun
Deer    1      9/22/2017            2         Muzzleloader
Deer    1      9/22/2017            3         Reg Bow
```

On 01/14/2017 and 09/22/2017 - a regular bow and crossbow were used to harvest deer so I would like to combine those into one set - but on 09/20/2017 and 09/22/2017 - only a crossbow or regular bow was used so this result should be left as it.

Is this possible?  I cannot think of a way to even begin to code this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you need, uses CTE but no UNION (tested) and is slightly more performant...

```
WITH HarvestResults AS
(
SELECT  Species,
        Total,
        HarvestMonthDayYear,
        CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') THEN 10 ELSE WeaponID END AS WeaponID,
        WeaponType,
        LAG(HarvestMonthDayYear,1) OVER(ORDER BY Species,HarvestMonthDayYear) AS PrevHarvestDate,
        LEAD(HarvestMonthDayYear,1) OVER(ORDER BY Species,HarvestMonthDayYear) AS NextHarvestDate,
        LAG(WeaponType,1) OVER(ORDER BY Species,HarvestMonthDayYear) AS PrevWeaponType,
        LEAD(WeaponType,1) OVER(ORDER BY Species,HarvestMonthDayYear) AS NextWeponType
FROM dbo.Harvest
)
SELECT  Species,
        SUM(Total) AS TOTAL,
        HarvestMonthDayYear,
        CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') 
             AND ((PrevHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear OR NextHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear)
             AND  (PrevWeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') OR NextWeponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow')))
             THEN 10 ELSE WeaponID END AS WeaponID,
        CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') 
             AND ((PrevHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear OR NextHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear)
             AND  (PrevWeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') OR NextWeponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow')))
             THEN 'Archery' ELSE WeaponType END AS WeaponType
FROM HarvestResults
GROUP BY Species,
         HarvestMonthDayYear,
         CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') 
              AND ((PrevHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear OR NextHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear)
              AND  (PrevWeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') OR NextWeponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow')))
              THEN 10 ELSE WeaponID END,
         CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') 
              AND ((PrevHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear OR NextHarvestDate = HarvestMonthDayYear)
              AND  (PrevWeaponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow') OR NextWeponType IN ('Crossbow','Reg Bow')))
              THEN 'Archery' ELSE WeaponType END
ORDER BY Species,
         HarvestMonthDayYear,
         WeaponID,
         WeaponType;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase this as a union:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Species, HarvestMonthDayYear, SUM(Total) AS Total
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE
        WeaponType IN ('Reg Bow', 'Crossbow')
    GROUP BY
        Species, HarvestMonthDayYear
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT WeaponType) = 2
)
SELECT
    t1.Species, t1.Total, t1.HarvestMonthDayYear, t1.WeaponID, t1.WeaponType
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Species = t2.Species AND
       t1.HarvestMonthDayYear = t2.HarvestMonthDayYear
WHERE
    t2.Species IS NULL OR
    (t2.Species IS NOT NULL AND WeaponType NOT IN ('Reg Bow', 'Crossbow'))
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Species, Total, HarvestMonthDayYear, 10, 'Archery'
FROM cte;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Without TCE :

```
SELECT Species, HarvestMonthDayYear, SUM(Total) AS Total
    , CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Reg Bow', 'Crossbow') THEN 10 ELSE WeaponID END AS WeaponID
    , MAX(CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Reg Bow', 'Crossbow') THEN 'Archery' ELSE WeaponType END) AS WeaponType 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
     Species, HarvestMonthDayYear
     , (CASE WHEN WeaponType IN ('Reg Bow', 'Crossbow') THEN 10 ELSE WeaponID END)
```